# i am working on an app. i'm getting error as below

Tags: android-studio

Gradle 'DoNotDisturb' project refresh failed
    Error:Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.

Searched in the following locations:

```
file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom

file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.jar

https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom

https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.jar
```

Required by:

```
project :
```

Comment: try to go to project settings, libraries and add a new maven library, look for: 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3' and add it to your project

Answer (score -1):

If you are opening an existing project follow the prompts to automatically update your project. Or try to clean rebuild and restarting android studio.

Comment: while true it's not very useful and should be published as a comment

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment.

Comment: So keep publishing *good* answers. Don't use answers as comment, this is not acceptable here.